# For each in list, do operation until condition is met

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Consider the following code:

```
void tryToOpenSafe() {
    getCorrectSafeCombination().subscribe(combination -> System.out.println("Correct combination is " + combination));
}

Maybe<Integer> getCorrectSafeCombination() {
    return getPossibleCombinations()
            .toObservable()
            .flatMapIterable(combinations -> combinations)
            .flatMap(combination -> tryToOpenSafeWithCombination(combination).toObservable()
                    .map(isCorrect -> new CombinationCheckResult(combination, isCorrect)))
            .filter(result -> result.isCorrect)
            .map(result -> result.combination)
            .firstElement();

}

Single<List<Integer>> getPossibleCombinations() {
    final List<Integer> combinations = Arrays.asList(123, 456, 789, 321);
    return Single.just(combinations);
}

// this is expensive
final Single<Boolean> tryToOpenSafeWithCombination(int combination) {
    System.out.println("Trying to open safe with " + combination);
    final boolean isCorrectCombination = combination == 789;
    return Single.just(isCorrectCombination);
}
```

I receive a list of possible "combinations" (integer) for a safe I want to open. Only one combination is the correct one of course.

With my current approach, `getCorrectSafeCombination()` will deliver the first correct combination it found; but it will try all the combinations nonetheless.

This is in efficient though: as soon as the correct combination is found, there is no need to try the others.

How can this be done with Rx?

Comment: What java version are you using? From what I remember, before Java 10 - flatMap is eager operation.

Comment: @Worthless Using Java 8. The flatMap operator belongs to RxJava and shouldn't change between Java versions, right?

Comment: And cant you use plain for and `break` out of it ? I see no real benefit of using rxjs (and hardly I see streams here) It is supposed to make life easier, not harder

Comment: This is of course an example. My real world scenario is such that is needs to be using Rx and actually profits from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `flatMap` is used for concurrent processing of observables while you need sequential. To fix that you just need to change your `flatMap` to `concatMap` to ensure sequential flow of observables in your `getCorrectSafeCombination` method:

```
Maybe<Integer> getCorrectSafeCombination() {
    return getPossibleCombinations()
            .toObservable()
            .flatMapIterable(combinations -> combinations)
            //this one
            .concatMap(combination -> tryToOpenSafeWithCombination(combination).toObservable()
                    .map(isCorrect -> new CombinationCheckResult(combination, isCorrect)))
            .filter(result -> result.isCorrect)
            .map(result -> result.combination)
            .firstElement();

}
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple, but couldn't see it.